# How to get link from object returned by imgur api

Tags: php, laravel, imgur

I am using:
1. Laravel 5
2. https://github.com/MarkRedeman/Imgur-Laravel

My Controller:

```
public function store()
    {
        $input = Request::all();

        $upload = new Upload($input);

        $upload->save();

        $upload_id = $upload->id;

        $path =  $this->resizeAndSaveTempImage($upload->raw_image_url);

        $done = $this->uploadToImgur($path);

        dd($done);



    }

public function resizeAndSaveTempImage($image_url)
    {


        $img = Image::make($image_url)->insert('http://i.imgur.com/Ned0D1ub.jpg', 'top', 130, 330);

        $tmp_name = 'final-output-' . microtime(true) . '.jpg';

        $path = 'tmp/' . $tmp_name;

        $img->save($path);

        return $path;



    }

    public function uploadToImgur($image_path)
    {
        $imageData = array(
            'image' => $image_path,
            'type'  => 'file',
            'name' => 'Lipsum',
            'title' => 'Lorem Ipsum',
            'description' => 'Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet'
        );

        $basic = Imgur::api('image')->upload($imageData);

        return $basic;
    }
```

The result of die and dump:

```
Basic {#236 ▼
  -data: array:20 [▼
    "id" => "KWIhRsS"
    "title" => "Lorem Ipsum"
    "description" => "Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet"
    "datetime" => 1431732751
    "type" => "image/jpeg"
    "animated" => false
    "width" => 640
    "height" => 640
    "size" => 95601
    "views" => 0
    "bandwidth" => 0
    "vote" => null
    "favorite" => false
    "nsfw" => null
    "section" => null
    "account_url" => null
    "account_id" => 0
    "deletehash" => "z8M21wNHdsFOBhJ"
    "name" => "Lipsum"
    "link" => "http://i.imgur.com/KWIhRsS.jpg"
  ]
  -success: true
  -status: 200
}
```

But if I try to access the link

```
dd($done->data['link']);
```

It gives me this error:

```
Cannot access private property Imgur\Api\Model\Basic::$data
```

How do i access the link from the the response object?

Answer (score 0):

After investigating the code HERE:

https://github.com/Adyg/php-imgur-api-client/blob/master/lib/Imgur/Api/Model/Basic.php

which the package Im using extends, there exists a getter for the $data property of the returned object.

```
$done->getData()
```